# Rename and synonym [ibooks] to [books]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

In iOS 12 iBooks was renamed to Books. Shouldn’t we rename the iBooks tag to Books and make iBooks a synonym of Books?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that makes sense. I've merged both [ibooks](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ibooks) and [ibookstore](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ibookstore) into [books](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/books) ([ibookstore](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ibookstore) was almost never used independently of [ibooks](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ibooks) anyway) and updated the tag wiki and excerpt. Since iBooks Author is, strangely enough, still called **i**Books Author, I've left the [ibooks-author](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ibooks-author) tag as it is.